# VNC session on Ubuntu 16 with Gnome looks like gray "theme"

Tags: gnome, vnc

This is not the gray screen from many other questions in this forum. It looks like something in the window manager fails. An image is attached here

[image: gray theme vnc ubuntu 16 with gnome]

What can be done in order to run gnome window manager properly?

Comment: It will help if several pieces of information are included:  What vnc server and client you are using, what OS's are involved (`uname -a`) and the version of gnome being run (`gnome-shell --version`)